# I can not run my code Tensorflow

Tags: python, compiler-errors, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I working on `Ubuntu 14.04` ,i wrote a code for Recognition of letters whith `Tensorflow V 0.11` ,
i'm creat a code source for uses the model `LeNet5` 
my code source :

`

```
import PIL

import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import Input as input_data
from tensorflow.python.framework.importer import import_graph_def

from Resize import Resize_img

# these functions to optimize the accurancy of the mnist training
#from imp_image import imp_img
import scipy.misc


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


# ============================================================ End Functions part

# mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

class MNIST:

    def __init__(self):

        # Open the compuation session
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        # Load the network
        self.Deep_Network()

    def Deep_Network(self):

        # nodes for the input images and target output classes.
        # supervised classifier
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
        self.y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

        # First convolutionanal Layer =====================================
        # It will consist of convolution, followed by max pooling
        # The convolutional will compute 32 features for each 5x5 patch.
        self.W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
        self.b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

        # To apply the layer, we first reshape x to a 4d tensor,
        #  with the second and third dimensions corresponding to image width and height,
        #  and the final dimension corresponding to the number of color channels.
        self.x_image = tf.reshape(self.x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

        # We then convolve x_image with the weight tensor, add the bias, apply the ReLU function, and finally max pool.
        self.h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(self.x_image, self.W_conv1) + self.b_conv1)
        self.h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(self.h_conv1)

        # Second Convolutional Layer =====================================

        # In order to build a deep network, we stack several layers of this type.
        # The second layer will have 64 features for each 5x5 patch.

        self.W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
        self.b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

        self.h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(self.h_pool1, self.W_conv2) + self.b_conv2)
        self.h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(self.h_conv2)

        # Densely Connected Layer

        # Now that the image size has been reduced to 7x7, we add a fully-connected layer with 1024 neurons
        # to allow processing on the entire image. We reshape the tensor from the pooling layer into
        # a batch of vectors, multiply by a weight matrix, add a bias, and apply a ReLU.

        self.W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
        self.b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

        self.h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(self.h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
        self.h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(
            tf.matmul(self.h_pool2_flat, self.W_fc1) + self.b_fc1)  # ReLu Computes rectified linear: max(features, 0).

        # Dropout

        self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        self.h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_fc1, self.keep_prob)

        # Readout Layer ========================================
        # Finally, we add a softmax layer, just like for the one layer softmax regression above.

        self.W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
        self.b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

        self.y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(self.h_fc1_drop, self.W_fc2) + self.b_fc2)
        self.cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.y_ * tf.log(self.y_conv))
        self.correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(self.y_, 1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self.correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    def Prediction(self, imageName):

        # Load the trained model
        ' Restore the model '
        'here i should create the model saver'
        Saved_model_dir = '/home/brm17/Desktop/PFE/'
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(Saved_model_dir)

        'verifie if the saved model exists or not!'
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(self.sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            print '# No saved model found!'
            exit()  # exit the prgm

        # image_test = 'number-3.jpg'
        ResizedImage = Resize_img(imageName)

        ImageInput = ResizedImage.mnist_image_input.reshape(1, -1)

        print 'Predection > ', tf.argmax(self.y_conv, 1).eval(feed_dict={self.x: ImageInput, self.keep_prob: 1.0})

    # print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: myTestImg, y_: myLabel, keep_prob: 1.0}))


def main():
    image = '/home/brm17/Desktop/PFE/n2.jpeg'
    model = MNIST()
    model.Prediction(image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

`
```

if i run this code , he print the error :

```
brm17@Brahim:~/Desktop/PFE$ python LeNet5.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LeNet5.py", line 137, in <module>
    model.Prediction(image)
  File "LeNet5.py", line 120, in Prediction
    saver.restore(self.sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1129, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 710, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 908, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 958, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 978, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: Tensor name "Variable_1" not found in checkpoint files /home/brm17/Desktop/PFE/MNISTmodel-20000
     [[Node: save/restore_slice_1 = RestoreSlice[dt=DT_FLOAT, preferred_shard=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/restore_slice_1/tensor_name, save/restore_slice_1/shape_and_slice)]]
Caused by op u'save/restore_slice_1', defined at:
  File "LeNet5.py", line 137, in <module>
    model.Prediction(image)
  File "LeNet5.py", line 115, in Prediction
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 861, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 519, in build
    filename_tensor, vars_to_save, restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 272, in _AddRestoreOps
    values = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, vs, preferred_shard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 187, in restore_op
    preferred_shard=preferred_shard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 203, in _restore_slice
    preferred_shard, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 359, in _restore_slice
    preferred_shard=preferred_shard, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2317, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

what is the problem and how resolved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Covißio,

I think the problem is as follows:

- You created a network, and saved this network...
- You changed the network, and did not remove the saved network
- Now you try to reload your network from an old version, but a new variable you created does not exist.

Can you try to either:

- Remove the saved state of your network and retrain it
- Remove the saving and loading of your network and see if this works?
  You can remove the state of your network by removing the checkpoint file in your folder /home/brm17/Desktop/PFE/

Edit: read your code thoroughly and the problem is that if there is no checkpoint you dont start retraining your network... Maybe you start by writing this before saving, loading, and changing your network.

Good luck and let me know if this works!

Comment: But he print : `# No saved model found!`